# Jenkins publishers postBuildScripts doesn't work

Tags: jenkins, groovy, publisher, post-build

I have a groovy script to setup a scheduled job in Jenkins.
I want to execute some shell scripts on failed build.
If I had the scripts manually after the job creation after the job is updated by groovy script, they run.
But the groovy script does not add it:

```
job('TestingAnalysis') {

  triggers {
    cron('H 8 28 * *')
  }

  steps {
    shell('some jiberish to create error')
  }
  publishers {
    postBuildScripts {
        steps {
          shell('echo "fff"')
          shell('echo "FFDFDF"')
          }
        onlyIfBuildSucceeds(false)
        onlyIfBuildFails(true)
    }
    retryBuild {
        rerunIfUnstable()
        retryLimit(3)
        fixedDelay(600)
    }
  }
}
```

Every thing works fine except:

```
    postBuildScripts {
        steps {
          shell('echo "fff"')
          shell('echo "FFDFDF"')
          }
        onlyIfBuildSucceeds(false)
        onlyIfBuildFails(true)
    }
```

This is my result:
[image]

I tried `postBuildSteps` and also got error.

I tried also with error:

```
    postBuildScripts {
        steps {
          sh' echo "ggg" '
          }
        onlyIfBuildSucceeds(false)
        onlyIfBuildFails(true)
    }
```

Comment: I just tested it and it works fine, which version of the `PostBuildScript` plugin are you using?

Comment: I use  version 3.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [JENKINS-66189](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-66189) seems like there is an issue with version 3.0 of the `PostBuildScript` in which the old syntax (that you are using) is no longer supported. In order to use the new version it in a Job Dsl script you will need to use [Dynamic DSL syntax](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Dynamic-DSL).

Use the following link in your own Jenkins instance to see the correct usage:
*YOUR_JENKINS_URL/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html#path/freeStyleJob-publishers-postBuildScript*.
it will help you build the correct command. In your case it will be:

```
job('TestingAnalysis') {
    triggers {
        cron('H 8 28 * *')
    }
    steps {
        shell('some jiberish to create error')
    }
    publishers {
        postBuildScript {
            buildSteps {
                postBuildStep {
                    stopOnFailure(false) // Mandatory setting
                    results(['FAILURE']) // Replaces onlyIfBuildFails(true)
                    buildSteps {
                        shell {
                            command('echo "fff"')
                        }
                        shell {
                            command('echo "FFDFDF"')
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            markBuildUnstable(false)  // Mandatory setting
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that instead of using functions like `onlyIfBuildSucceeds` and `onlyIfBuildFails` you now just pass a list of relevant build results to the `results` function. (*SUCCESS*,*UNSTABLE*,*FAILURE*,*NOT_BUILT*,*ABORTED*)